# Computing daily minimum and maximum of columns in pandas dataframe spanning multiple days

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. dataframe with hourly data:

```
                            tmp            min_tmp          max_tmp
dates                                                             
2017-07-19 14:00:00         19.0             19.0             19.0
2017-07-19 15:00:00         18.0             18.0             18.0
2017-07-19 16:00:00         16.0             16.0             16.0
2017-07-19 17:00:00         16.0             16.0             16.0
2017-07-19 18:00:00         15.0             15.0             15.0
```

Is there a way we can compute daily minimum and maximum values of `tmp` in `min_tmp` and `max_tmp` respectively. I tried this

```
df['min_temp'] = df['tmp'].min()
```

but this does not work for dataframe data that spans multiple days

Comment: You have to group your data by day and then aggregate to the min/max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `resample` and `transform`:

```
g = df.resample('D')['tmp']

df['min_tmp'] = g.transform('min')

df['max_tmp'] = g.transform('max')
```

Output

```
                      tmp  min_tmp  max_tmp
dates                                      
2017-07-19 14:00:00  19.0     15.0     19.0
2017-07-19 15:00:00  18.0     15.0     19.0
2017-07-19 16:00:00  16.0     15.0     19.0
2017-07-19 17:00:00  16.0     15.0     19.0
2017-07-19 18:00:00  15.0     15.0     19.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the min/max computed by day. You have to group by day, month, and year simultaneously:

```
pd.groupby(df['tmp'], by=[df.index.day, df.index.month, df.index.year]).min()
```

Answer (score 0):

`transform` in `pandas`

```
 df['Date']=df.index
 df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
 map={'min_tmp':min, 'max_tmp':max}
    for key,value in map.items():
        print(key,value)
        df[key]=df.groupby(df.Date.dt.date)['tmp'].transform(func=value)

 df.drop(['Date'],axis=1)

Out[469]: 
                 tmp  min_tmp  max_tmp
Date                                  
7/19/2017 14:00   19       15       19
7/19/2017 15:00   18       15       19
7/19/2017 16:00   16       15       19
7/19/2017 17:00   16       15       19
7/19/2017 18:00   15       15       19
```

I am lazy for repeating, but you can simply do this to achieve.

```
df['max_tmp']=df.groupby(df.Date.dt.date)['tmp'].transform(max)
df['min_tmp']=df.groupby(df.Date.dt.date)['tmp'].transform(min)
```